IConfiguration showing duplicate entries .NET Core 6
I have .NET 6 application and environment based appsetting ie. appsettings.json and appsettings.staging.json
Sample entries in appsettings.json


KeyName": [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Code": "Cod1",
    "Description": "Description",
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "Code": "Cod2",
    "Description": "Description 2",
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Name 3",
    "Code": "Cod3",
    "Description": "Description 3"
  }
]



and appsettings.staging.json are


"KeyName": [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Code": "Cod1",
    "Description": "Description",
  },
]



and when i am trying to fetch data using
Configuration.GetSection("KeyName").Bind(deliveryServicesList).Get<List<T>>()
I get following


[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Code": "Cod1",
    "Description": "Description",
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "Code": "Cod2",
    "Description": "Description 2",
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Name 3",
    "Code": "Cod3",
    "Description": "Description 3"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Code": "Cod1",
    "Description": "Description",
  }
]



While i only expect below


[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Code": "Cod1",
    "Description": "Description",
  }]



Any idea what i am missing
I tried different options changing keynames, order changes etc

By default, the .NET Core config system will load both the appsettings.json and the appsettings.{environment}.json file and return all elements contained in both files - which is exactly what you're seeing.

@marc_s i should see based on environment instead of combined data

you should move all environment-dependent data out of appsettings.json because as @marc_s said, appsettings.json is loaded first always, and then the environment configuration is added on top of the base config, overwriting any existing configurations and possibly adding new configuration data.

so instead of hardcoding the configuration (which would be one way to get what you want), you should instead rethink your approach. appsettings.json should only contain common stuff that exist in every environment (such as connection strings, CORS settings etc.), and appsettings.{environment}.json should be where you introduce dynamic/environment-dependent configurations. This would mean using a apsettings.Development.json in local development and moving those three items in there. Check launchSettings.json to see your local environment (which will be ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)

@EmreBener thanks for the suggestion, But one of the key is working fine in both files

@ZahidMustafa what do you mean by "one of the key is working fine in both files"?
